# How to receive data from database through ajax call in codeigniter?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter, get

What I need is to receive data from database in Json format, and I am coding I suppose pretty right but I don't know why every time I receive "Failed" response. I m using codeigniter.

My ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url  : 'get_trip_data',
    data: "",
    dataType: 'json', 

    success: function(result){

        console.log('Success');
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(result){
      console.log('Failed');
      console.log(result);
    }
 });
```

My controller:

```
    public function get_trip_data()
    {       
        $result = $this->db->get('book_trip')->result_array();
        $trip = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach($result as $r)
        {           
            $trip[$i]['id'] =  $r['book_id'];
            $trip[$i]['text'] =  $r['book_name'];
            $trip[$i]['start'] =  $r['date_travel'];
            $trip[$i]['end'] =  $r['date_returrn'];
            $i=$i+1;            
        }
        return json_encode($trip);
    }
```

Even if I return only "$result", this call is not working.

Note: When I directly hit route, I get all data properly in json format.
Could you suggest what is wrong?

P.s: I have searched all way google and over stack overflow, but nothing solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller

Instead of return, you can 'echo'.

Also, In view's success and error part, you should parse results.

Follow next.

var res = JSON.parse(result);
console.log(res);

Answer (score 0):

Use '/' in url before route name or write down whole path like with domain name + route

```
$.ajax({
type:'get',
url  : '/get_trip_data', //considering  get_trip_data is also in route 
data: "",
dataType: 'json', 

success: function(result){

    console.log('Success');
    console.log(result);
},
error: function(result){
  console.log('Failed');
  console.log(result);
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks for response but it doesn't make any difference. Already tried

Comment: check the network tab in developer tool. check what you are getting in a  response

Answer (score 0):

If directly accessing the route outputs the right json, then it means you have the wrong URL on your ajax request. Try to change the ajax url like this :

```php
    url  : '<?php echo site_url(); ?>/controllerName/get_trip_data',
```

Change the `controllerName` to whatever the controller name you have on your `get_trip_data` method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering everyone.
Issue I found myself and it was:

```
return json_encode($trip)
```

When I changed it to:

```
echo json_encode($trip)
```

Everything worked fine.